# octave error on running the below code for antenna

Tags: octave

error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x101) thia is the error on executing this line-iz(1,n-1)=sin((1-m)*pi*(lambda))

the entire code is:

```matlab
lambda=1
m=input('Enter the length of dipole(in terms of lambda) =    ')
l=m*lambda
m=1:0.01:1
r=m
iz=zeros(1,length(m))
n=1
j=2*length(m)-length(m)
for 
m=-1:0.01:0;
iz(1,n)=sin((1+m)*pi*(lambda))
n=n+1
end
for
m=0:0.01:1;
iz(1,n-1)=sin((1-m)*pi*(lambda))
n=n+1
end
plot(iz(1,:),r)
grid on
ylabel('current')
xlabel('length')
```

Comment: Please format your code. You need operators between the braket and pi. I guess you want a Multiplikation * op

Comment: i have error in this line- iz(1,n)=sin((1+m)*pi*(lambda)) and the error shows this -error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x101)

Comment: even same erroris shown in this line also- iz(1,n-1)=sin((1-m)*pi*(lambda))

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is the format of your for loops. The following code runs without errors, although I'm not entirely sure it is doing what you intend it to do.

```matlab
lambda=1
m=input('Enter the length of dipole(in terms of lambda) =    ')
l=m*lambda
m=1:0.01:1 % This is the same thing as saying m=1, is that what you want?
r=m
iz=zeros(1,length(m));
n=1
j=2*length(m)-length(m);% This is the same thing as saying j=length(m) (which is 1)
for m=-1:0.01:0
    iz(1,n)=sin((1+m)*pi*(lambda));
    n=n+1;
end
for m=0:0.01:1
    iz(1,n-1)=sin((1-m)*pi*(lambda));
    n=n+1;
end
plot(iz(1,:),r)
grid on
ylabel('current')
xlabel('length')
```

Comment: i want to plot this euations here

Comment:  (′ = 0, ′ = 0, ′) = {
̂ 0 sin [ (

2
− ′)] , 0 ≤ ′ ≤ /2
̂ 0 sin [ (

2
+ ′)] , − /2 ≤ ′ ≤ 0
Fig.

Answer (score 0):

%----------------------------------------------------------------------

clc

clear all

close all

%----- Current Distribution of dipole antenna for various length -------

%------Entering the length by lambda ---

L_lambda=input('Enter the length (in terms of lambda) = ')

p=input('enter number of points on the curve = ')

%------------------------------------------------------------------

m=-1:(2/p):1 ; % defining number of points for length (L/2)

% towards positive and negative Z axis

I_z=zeros(1,length(m));

n=1;

for m=-1:(2/p):0

I_z(1,n)=sin((1+m)*pi*(L_lambda));

n=n+1;

end

for m=0:(2/p):1

I_z(1,n-1)=sin((1-m)*pi*(L_lambda));

n=n+1;

end

m=-1:(2/p):1;

plot(I_z(1,:),m)

xlabel('Current I')

ylabel('Length')

title('Current distribution for finite length dipole')

grid

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------